# PlayFramework2 : can't find sbt dependencies in build path

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

Here's my build.sbt

```
name := """project_name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",
  "com.alibaba" % "fastjson" % "1.1.21"
)
```

I'm trying to use `fastjson` from `com.alibaba`,sbt download it correctly:

```
[info] Updating {file:/activator-1.2.3-minimal/projects/project_name/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/alibaba/fastjson/1.1.21/fastjson-1.1.21.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.alibaba#fastjson;1.1.21!fastjson.jar (14138ms)
[info] Done updating.
```

But I still can't find it in my build path and can't use it in my code(`Eclipse can't find fastjson classess`).

Answer (score 0):

If SBT can build it, but Eclipse can't, try to regenerate Eclipse project from SBT: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE